# Updating branch protection settings via Github API

Tags: node.js, github-api

[Github API - Update Branch Protection](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/branches/#update-branch-protection)

I am trying to update the branch protection settings for a repo on github to set `Require pull request reviews before merging` to true. I am using the node [`request`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) library to make the request.

```
protectBranch: function(github, org, repo, branch) {
    return new Promise((result, reject) => {
        let options = {
            'url' : github+'/repos/'+org+'/'+repo+'/branches/'+branch+'/protection',
            headers: {
                'User-Agent': 'nola-guilds-github',
                'Authorization': 'token '+process.env.GITHUB_TOKEN,
                'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.loki-preview+json'
            },
            body: {
                'required_status_checks' : {
                    'include_admins' : false,
                    'strict' : true,
                    'contexts' : ['default']
                },
                'required_pull_request_review' : {
                    'include_admins' : false
                },
                'restrictions' : null,
                'enforce_admins' : false
            },
            json: true
        }
        request.put(options, function (error, response, body) {
            if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
                result();
            } else {
                if (error) {
                    reject(error);
                } else {
                    reject(response);
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I get a 200 response code, and everything else is set correctly, but this one setting. I am at a loss for what the problem could be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a **`s`** at `required_pull_request_reviews` :

```
body: {
    'required_status_checks': {
        'include_admins': false,
        'strict': true,
        'contexts': ['default']
    },
    'required_pull_request_reviews': {
        'include_admins': false
    },
    'restrictions': null,
    'enforce_admins': false
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now I am feeling ridiculous.